# Why does the wrong button take the Enter key?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, ngx-bootstrap

I have an Angular 13 form, and in it are a few buttons. This one is to add a new row to the form:

```
<div class="col-md-2 offset-md-8">
    <button class="badge rounded-pill bg-secondary mt-2"
            (click)="addRow()">Add compound ingredient</button>
  </div>
```

For some reason, this button takes the default Enter key event.

If you add a row using the above button, the new row has this button next to it, to remove that row. If it is visible, it actually takes the Enter key event.

```
    <div class="col-md-1"
         *ngIf="index > 0">
      <button class="badge rounded-pill bg-secondary mt-2"
              (click)="removeRow(index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
```

This is the button that I WANT to have the Enter key event.

```
  <div class="col-md-2 d-grid">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
            accesskey="s"
            tooltip="Alt-S"
            (click)="getData()">Send</button>
  </div>
```

I have tried adding the `type="submit"` property, and that doesn't do it. In the meantime I've added the `accesskey`, but that's not what I want in the long run for the form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In Angular all the buttons by defect are of type "submit" (when use ENTER dispatch the even). Use `type=button`: e.g. `<button type="button" ....>send</button>`

Comment: Are all the buttons surrounded by `<form></form>` tags? Because then the button with role or type ="submit" should get catch the ENTER key

Comment: Setting the other buttons to `type="button"` solved the problem of the other buttons getting the event, and then I realized that this button was outside the form, so I put it into the form and everything works as expected now. Thanks to both of you, as it did require both changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up having to add the `type="button"` to the buttons that I don't want catching the event, add `type="submit"` to the desired button, and then had to make sure that the desired button was within the `<form></form>` tags, which it was not.

Answer (score 0):

I think onKeyDownEvent is what you are actually searching for.

I would create a handler function which you would use as the handler function when the event is fired.

In the handler i would react according to the sender (the button from which the event is fired).

You could maybe also use the tabindex to make the second button click first when the uswr hits enter. But i am not sure if the tabindex is the right thing for that.

Also by calling the Event.stopPropagation() function in your handler function you can stop other elements reacting to the event.